# The problem with the implementation of passwords

Tags: node.js, express, roles

I have three roles:

`1) User`

`2) Merchant`

`3) Admin`

Each role has its own authorization route:

`1) .../api/users/singin`

`2) .../api/merchants/singin`

`3) .../api/admins/singin`

I also have resources:

`1) Products`

But more resources will be added.

Products can be deleted, edited, added.

For example, I log in on the route `.../api/merchants/singin` for the seller and give the token:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import config from './../config';

router.post('/singin', async (req, res) => {
    const JWTToken = jwt.sign({
        ...
        roles: 'merchant',
        }, config.keySecret.secret, {
            expiresIn: config.keySecret.expires
        }
    );
    ...
    return res.status(200).json({
        token: JWTToken
    });
});
```

For the administrator and the user, the structure is the same, only the role and information about the user and the seller change.

I sent to the client a seller token containing information about the seller and his `merchant` role.

The administrator has all the rights, the seller can only add products, change and delete, the user can only view the products.

Now the seller’s token comes to me from the client and on the route, for example, adding a product:

```
router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
jwt.verify(
    req.headers.token, config.keySecret.secret,  (err) => {
        if (err, decoded) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                name: 'TokenExpiredError',
                message: 'jwt expired'
            });
        }
        if (decoded.role !== 'merchant') {
            res.status(200).json({
                err: 'Not accessing this role'
            });
        }  
        ....
});
```

I have problems from now on.

How to verify that a role has the right to add a product? What can only view the product? How to check that she has all the rights? Now only the seller can add the product. How to make the administrator to add a product, too, I do not have to write such a structure on each route? Since I have not only products will be.

```
    if (decoded.role !== 'merchant' || 'admin') {
        res.status(200).json({
            err: 'Not accessing this role'
        });
    }
```

Or when you need to see the list of products:

```
    if (decoded.role !== 'merchant' || 'admin' || 'user') {
        res.status(200).json({
            err: 'Not accessing this role'
        });
    }
```

How to implement role access so I don’t have to write `if (decoded.role! == ....)`?

Or how to do it correctly, if I did not put it correctly above.

Comment: If you have a user table in your database, add a column for user role. then assign roles for each users. after that when you have a token check whether that user has that privilege using that table. then you can decide what you have to do next

Comment: @Darshana Pathum I already have over 1000 users. There are also more than 50 sellers. Should I assign each user a shed? Are there any other options?